# Is there a way for selenium to move_to_element from last cursor position

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click a sequence of elements, and current using the ActionChains

It's the code to perform the task. But the problem is that it will scroll from the top of the webpage each time it's called.

`ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(ele).click().perform()`

As I have a sequence of elements, the further down the sequence, the more it will scroll over (click n-th element require scroll n elements) and result in overall O(n^2) efficiency.
I wonder is there a way to shrink it to linear, eg. move from the last cursor position

Comment: Selenium does not really move the cursor.  It generates events.  Are you saying the window actually scrolls up after a hover or click?

Comment: I am not sure if that's a "scroll up", seems like a "jump" as I can't see the scroll bar moving up, it's just at the top position right away. But for the "scroll down" I can see the bar slowly moves down to the element; basically, the actions will start from the top of the web at each iteration `loop: 
ele <- NEW_ELE  
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(ele).perform()`

Comment: I'm guessing it's generating a hover on that element and then the markup is doing something that triggers the scroll. Can you post the markup for the element?